# JUNG Simulation

Tags: vertex, jung

I'm doing a project in JUNG. I want to add a mouse event which will be called when the user will move a node or vertex.
I have tried multiple listeners like, ItemListener, GraphMouseListener..

I have tried this, n some similar codes:

```
          vv.addGraphMouseListener(new GraphMouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void graphClicked(Object v, MouseEvent me) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void graphPressed(Object v, MouseEvent me) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void graphReleased(Object v, MouseEvent me) {

           Object subject = me.getSource();
                // The graph uses Integers for vertices.
                if (subject instanceof VertexFactory) {
                    VertexFactory vertex = (VertexFactory) subject;
                    if (pickedState.isPicked(vertex)) {
//                        selectedNode = vertex;
                        System.out.println("Vertex " + vertex
                                + " is now selected");
                        re.calDistance(bs.get(0));
                        dest();
                        vv.repaint();
                        vv.updateUI();

                    }
                }
            }
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest extending the PickingGraphMousePlugin and adding it to your GraphMouse

http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/control/PickingGraphMousePlugin.html

```
public class MovingGraphMousePlugin<V, E> extends PickingGraphMousePlugin<V, E> {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mousePressed(e);
        if(vertex != null) {
            System.out.println(vertex + " was picked.");
        }
    }
}
```

and then for example:

```
DefaultModalGraphMouse graphMouse = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();
graphMouse.add(new MovingGraphMousePlugin<V, E>());
visualViewer.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);
```

This is just a rough example and will only tell you that a vertex has been picked. If you want to print if a vertex has been moved, you would have to override the `mouseReleased` method, too. 
You then would have to compare the two points where the mouse has been pressed and where it has been released (`e.getPoint()`).